# Turn columns with non-distinct values (from csv) into columns with unique/distinct values (saved in new csv) by using Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, unique, distinct

I want to turn my .csv-file with non-distinct values underneath each column header into a .csv with distinct values underneath each column header (just want to know all unique values for each column of a huge .csv-file). An example:

My initial .csv-file is visible (left) which in Excel is displayed as (see right):

```
A,B,C,D                                        A       B       C       D
1,CEN,T2,56                                    1       CEN     T2      56
2,DECEN,T3,45                                  2       DECEN   T3      45
1,ONBEK,T2,84                                  1       ONBEK   T2      84
1,CEN,T1,59                                    1       CEN     T1      59
2,CEN,T1,87                                    2       CEN     T1      87
```

where A, B, C and D are the column headers with each 5 values underneath.

My prefered output .csv file should look like (see left, right is when opened in Excel):

```
A,B,C,D                                        A       B       C       D
1,CEN,T2,56                                    1       CEN     T2      56
2,DECEN,T3,45                                  2       DECEN   T3      45
,ONBEK,T1,84                                           ONBEK   T1      84
,,,59                                                                  59
,,,87                                                                  87
```

where A, B, C and D are the column headers with underneath them only the distinct values for each column from the original .csv-file.

I tried using a Pandas dataframe to perform this task, however I don't manage to get my preferred output (I'm stuck at merging unique dataframes of each column together since they have a different length).

See the code below:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(csv_file, encoding='utf-8') #read .csv in pandas dataframe

columnnames = list(df.columns)
print(columnnames)

df2 = pd.DataFrame()

for col in df:
    result = df[col].unique()   #creates a list with distinct values
    print(result)
    output = pd.DataFrame(result)   #to transform the distinct list back into a dataframe
    print(output)
    df2.append(output) #tries to merge all the lists with unique values from the loop into the new dataframe df2
    df2.columns = columnnames
    print(df2)

df2.to_csv("c_" + csv_file, sep=',') #write pandas dataframe to .csv
```

Anybody any ideas?
Because I'm searching for distinct values in each column, each column can have a different length. Preferably those cells after the last distinct one are empty (see preferred output). If that's not possible, they can always be filled with 'NaN' or 'NULL' if necessary.

Comment: To be clear, you're trying to completely decouple all of the column values from one another but still include the data as columns?

Comment: Well, each column is independent of another and for each column I only want to keep the distinct values. So that I can say/see 'in column 'A', only this and this and this values are present; in column 'B', only this and this and this value is present; ... and so on and on.. There's no relation between the columns, just want to keep the distinct values per column.

Comment: Just wanted to double check that's what you wanted

Comment: Why keep that CSV format for the output, if all you want is the unique values?

Comment: Just to be able to open it in Excel afterwards. After checking the distinct values, I want to replace some of them (if necessary) by other values (which i'll maybe do in excel because it's a bit more hands on, don't know yet). This was just a small example of something I'm working on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One note off the bat: Dataframes aren't designed for columns of different lengths of data, so `NaN` values to pad the length make the most sense (as you noted in your question)

```
df

    A   B       C   D
0   1   CEN     T2  56
1   2   DECEN   T3  45
2   1   ONBEK   T2  84
3   1   CEN     T1  59
4   2   CEN     T1  87

new_df=pd.concat([pd.Series(df[i].unique()) for i in df.columns], axis=1)

new_df.columns=df.columns

new_df

    A   B       C   D
0   1.0 CEN     T2  56
1   2.0 DECEN   T3  45
2   NaN ONBEK   T1  84
3   NaN NaN     NaN 59
4   NaN NaN     NaN 87
```

Comment: Perfect! and the NaN leaves an empty cell when saving to .csv (just what I wanted)!

Comment: Glad I could solve the question for you as asked, though I have resevations about the application haha. You say in the comments "which i'll maybe do in excel because it's a bit more hands on", if you already have the data in a dataframe, I would encourage you to try some things working within the python ecosystem because it can be as powerful, if not more powerful, if you're doing it systematically

Comment: You're right, for lots of things Python is much more powerfull but as I'm still learning, it takes quite some time to get the code on point so some operations can be faster manually in Excel than hard-coded in Python for individual cases in a database. But sure, the goal is to do as much as possible in Python to improve my programming-skills. If it works, it's brilliant and fast.

Comment: If you are willing to, can you also help with this one? (it's a addition to this question with which I'm struggling for a while already today): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230730/get-unique-values-and-their-occurrence-out-of-one-dataframe-into-a-new-dataframe