# Get unique values and their occurrence out of one dataframe into a new dataframe using Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, count, unique

I want to turn my dataframe with non-distinct values underneath each column header into a dataframe with distinct values underneath each column header with next to it their occurrence in their particular column. An example:

My initial dataframe is visible underneath:

```
A       B       C       D
0       CEN     T2      56
2       DECEN   T2      45
3       ONBEK   T2      84
NaN     CEN     T1      59
3       NaN     T1      87
NaN     NaN     T2      NaN
0       NaN     NaN     98
NaN     CEN     NaN     23
NaN     CEN     T1      65
```

where A, B, C and D are the column headers with each 9 values underneath it (blanks included).

My preferred output dataframe should look like: (first a column of unique values for each column in the original dataframe and next to it their occurrence in that particular column)

```
A       B       C       D       A       B       C       D
0       CEN     T2      56      2       4       4       1
2       DECEN   T1      45      1       1       3       1
3       ONBEK   NaN     84      2       1       NaN     1
Nan     NaN     NaN     59      NaN     NaN     NaN     1
NaN     NaN     NaN     87      NaN     NaN     NaN     1
NaN     NaN     NaN     98      NaN     NaN     NaN     1
NaN     NaN     NaN     23      NaN     NaN     NaN     1
NaN     NaN     NaN     65      NaN     NaN     NaN     1
```

where A, B, C and D are the column headers with underneath them first the distinct values for each column from the original .csv-file and next to it the occurence of each element in their particular column.

Anybody ideas?

The code below is used to get the unique values out of each column into a new dataframe. I tried to do something with .value_counts to get the occurrence in each column but there I failed to get it into one dataframe again with the unique values..

```
df
new_df=pd.concat([pd.Series(df[i].unique()) for i in df.columns], axis=1)
new_df.columns=df.columns
new_df
```

Comment: column D has a NaN in input but not the output?

Comment: Well my DataFrame is read in from a .csv-file. and Python reads empty cells as NaN into a DataFrame.. so it should indeed not appear in the output ;-) (if I'm correct)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difficult part is keeping values of columns in each row aligned. To do this, you need to construct a new dataframe from `unique`, and `pd.concat` on with `value_counts` map to each column of this new dataframe.

```
new_df = (pd.DataFrame([df[c].unique() for c in df], index=df.columns).T
            .dropna(how='all'))

df_final = pd.concat([new_df, *[new_df[c].map(df[c].value_counts()).rename(f'{c}_Count') 
                                   for c in  df]], axis=1).reset_index(drop=True)

Out[1580]:
     A      B    C   D  A_Count  B_Count  C_Count  D_Count
0    0    CEN   T2  56      2.0      4.0      4.0        1
1    2  DECEN   T1  45      1.0      1.0      3.0        1
2    3  ONBEK  NaN  84      2.0      1.0      NaN        1
3  NaN    NaN  NaN  59      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
4  NaN    NaN  NaN  87      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
5  NaN    NaN  NaN  98      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
6  NaN    NaN  NaN  23      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
7  NaN    NaN  NaN  65      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
```

---

If you only need to keep alignment between each pair of column and its count such as `A` - `A_Count`, `B` - `B_Count`..., it simply just use `value_counts` with `reset_index` some commands to change axis names

```
cols = df.columns.tolist() + (df.columns + '_Count').tolist()
new_df = pd.concat([df[col].value_counts(sort=False).rename_axis(col).reset_index(name=f'{col}_Count') 
                        for col in df], axis=1).reindex(new_cols, axis=1)

Out[1501]:
     A      B    C     D  A_Count  B_Count  C_Count  D_Count
0  0.0  ONBEK   T2  56.0      2.0      1.0      4.0        1
1  2.0    CEN   T1  45.0      1.0      4.0      3.0        1
2  3.0  DECEN  NaN  84.0      2.0      1.0      NaN        1
3  NaN    NaN  NaN  59.0      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
4  NaN    NaN  NaN  87.0      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
5  NaN    NaN  NaN  98.0      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
6  NaN    NaN  NaN  23.0      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
7  NaN    NaN  NaN  65.0      NaN      NaN      NaN        1
```

Comment: This is it, perfect!! Is there no way to have the same result as in the first option but by resetting the index (now rownumber 5 is missing)? Do you have any idea why some of the values are saved as integers (e.g. '1' but other as decimals (e.g. '1.0')?

Comment: @Matthi9000: Oh, it is simple. Just add an additional `reset_index(drop=True)`. I edited the answer. On `1` and `1.0`, when column has `NaN` value, its dtype is forced to `float`, so `1` is converted to `1.0`